# Erro: platform not recognized as a core cordova pltatfomr

Tags: ionic, cordova-plugin

Tenho todo o ambiente configurado para o ionic,

Variáveis de ambiente:

> ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>
> No path tenho : %ANDROID_HOME%\tools e %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Versão do Ionic: 2.1.13

cordova = 6.4.0

Quando eu encontro na pasta do projeto que efetuo o comando:

> ionic platform add android

Tenho o erro:

> Error: platform “android” not recognized as a core cordova pltatfomr.
>   See ‘cordova platform list’

Comment: no seu erro temos "pltatfomr". Será que não seria esse aí o erro? Não deveria ser: "platform"?

Comment: correto! valeu!

Comment: resolveu o problema?!